# How do I uninstall a package in Elm?

Tags: installation, uninstallation, elm

If I have installed a package with `elm install *package name*` how do I then uninstall it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way with the included `elm` tool, though [elm-json](https://github.com/zwilias/elm-json) is a common tool that can do that.

You can also just remove the dependency from your `elm.json` file (though `elm-json` will take care of indirect dependencies that might be affected).